# How to extract just domain names from urls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a following list of URLs:

```
urls = ["http://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08097", "https://doi.org/10.1109/tkde.2016.2598561", "https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=85116544648&origin=inward"]
```

from each element of the list, I am trying to extract just the domain names like: `arxiv`, `doi`, `scopus`.

For that I have a code:

```
import re

for url in urls:
    print(re.search('https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*', url).group(1))
```

The output of print:

```
arxiv.org
doi.org
www.scopus.com
```

How can I modify the above regex to extract just the domain and no other stuff like `www.`, `.com`, `.org` etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you have something like `www.sub.domain.co.uk`?

Comment: @mozway That'll never be the case

Comment: So it's always `A.B.C` or `B.C` and you want `B`?

Comment: @mozway yes, exactly

Comment: Ok, I [modified your regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70188031/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the dot from the character class and make www. optional. The value is in capture group 1.

```
https?://(?:www\.)?([A-Za-z_0-9-]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTqHgm/1)

Answer (score 2):

To get only the second to last chunks of the domain, you could modify your regex to have:

```
[re.search('https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?([A-Za-z_0-9-]+)\.[^/.]+(?:/.*)?', url).group(1)
 for url in urls]
```

Output:

```
['arxiv', 'doi', 'scopus']
```

###### urllib

@AbdulNiyasPM had a nice answer, too bad it was deleted, you can modify it to get what you want:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
[urlparse(url).hostname.split('.')[-2]
 for url in urls]
```